# How I supposed to change these mongo query to Php

Tags: php, mongodb

```
db.clicks_data_2.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            $sort : { _id: 1 } 
        },
        {
            "$limit": 25000  
        },
        {
            $group : { 
                _id: {
                    interval_start: "$interval_start", 
                    ad_id: "$ad_id", 
                    zone_id: "$zone_id",
                    isExcluded: "$isExcluded", 
                    app_id: "$app_id" ,
                    screen_name: "$screen_name", 
                    ad_group_id : "$ad_group_id",  
                    product_id: "$product_id", 
                    country: "$country",  
                    is_incent: "$is_incent"
                }, 
                oid: {$push :"$_id"}, 
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
         }
     ], 
     {
         cursor: { batchSize: 10000 }
     }
)
```

Please help me to convert these query to php format

Comment: What have you tried? Last time I checked you just wrote `array()` or `[]` where the curlies `{}` are,  and use `=>` where the colons `:` are.

Comment: anything in mongo with this `"$limit"` in php must be done this way `"\$limit"`  you have to escape the dollar sign, or php with interpolate ( think its a variable )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this, note - untested

```
$collection->aggregate(
    [
        [
            '$sort' => [ '_id'=> 1 ] 
        ],
        [
            '$limit'=> 25000  
        ],
        [
            '$group' => [ 
                '_id'=> [
                    'interval_start'=> "\$interval_start", 
                    'ad_id'=> "\$ad_id", 
                    'zone_id'=> "\$zone_id",
                    'isExcluded'=> "\$isExcluded", 
                    'app_id'=> "\$app_id" ,
                    'screen_name'=> "\$screen_name", 
                    'ad_group_id' => "\$ad_group_id",  
                    'product_id'=> "\$product_id", 
                    'country'=> "\$country",  
                    'is_incent'=> "\$is_incent"
                ], 
                'oid'=> ['$push' =>"\$_id"], 
                'count'=> ['$sum'=> 1 ]
            ]
        ]
     ], 
     [
         'cursor'=> [ 'batchSize'=> 10000 ]
     ]
);
```

As a general rule I use single quote`'` on the left side of the `=>` and double on the right `"` anything on the right with a `$` and `"` needs to be escaped like `"\$var"` because PHP will treat this `"$var"` as something it should replace -via- variable interpolation ( unless that's your intention ) as mongo allows you to reference variables using `"$var"` which is nice but doesn't play well with PHP.

You'll also want to learn how to cast int's such as `(int)$id` in PHP because mongo is type sensitive and PHP is not.  But, that's another topic for another day.

Another useful "tip" is to json_encode your input and check that against what you need in mongo, it should be real or more similar.

UPDATE:

in mongo you can do things like this

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: "$date"}, year: { $year: "$date" } },
           totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

This line is of interest specifically

```
 totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
```

What this does is multiply the value of `price` by the value of `quantity`.  Now you cannot just put that in PHP as I mentioned because of variable interpolation, PHP will think `$price` is a variable it needs to replace.

That said we can do the same thing this way.

```
  totalAmount => [ '$sum'=> [ '$multiply' => [ "\$price", "\$quantity" ] ]],
```

By `escaping` the `$` sign.

Comment: Why not just use `''` around the strings with `$`?

Comment: because in mongo, you have to use `"$field"` for variables to reference fields such as for counting and projection.  See update...

Comment: `'$field'` is perfectly fine for PHP. Point is to not interpolate, which does not happen with the different type of quotes. So escaping is not necessary. Get it now? Helps not to promote bad coding practices.

Comment: I found that mongo will not see this `'$field'` as the same thing as `"$field"` but instead as a string literal.

Comment: You found wrong. It's perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix